# Find the tangent line to a rose in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, tangent-line

Let $C$ be the rose defined in polar coordinates as $r = 2\cos(2\theta), \theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

1. Find all points $(x(\theta), y(\theta))$ in $C$, for which the slope of the tangent line to $C$ at $(x(\theta),y(\theta))$ is equal to $\tan(\theta)$.
2. Deduce from part 1 that there is no circle $S$ with positive radius centered at the origin, for which $C$ and $S$ would intersect perpendicularly at some point.

From what I understand, if there were some $\theta$ such that the slope of $C$ at $\theta$ was equal to $\tan(\theta)$ Then part 2 of this question would be wrong, because $y=x\cdot \tan(\theta)$ is a normal line to any circle at $\theta$. So the only way part 2 is true, is if there are no solutions to part 1, or if the solutions are any $\theta$ such that $r=0$.

However, attempting part 1 we get
$$x(\theta) = 2\cos(2\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
$$y(\theta) = 2\cos(2\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y(\theta + h) - y(\theta)}{x(\theta+h) - x(\theta)}$$
which using L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate the limit (by taking the partial derivative with respect to $h$ and then plugging in $h=0$ gives us
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y'(\theta)}{x'(\theta)}$$
Actually doing the derivative and setting this equal to $\tan(\theta)$ finally gives us the equation
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{4\cos(2\theta)\sin(\theta)-2\cos(2\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2\cos(2\theta)\sin(\theta)+4\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta)}$$

Playing around with trig identities for a while gives us some answers, plugging it into wolfram alpha gives different answers, probably as I made a mistake, but in either case, we do get 4 solutions, and none of them are ones that make $r=0$. So I don't understand how part 2 could be correct.

Comment: Its important to ask where these happen. I believe they happen at $\pi/4 + npi/2$. Why does this not contradict anything?

Comment: @TheHype Except they don't happen at those values.

Comment: [Here](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/), run the numbers again.

Comment: Yeap, you're right, thanks

Comment: FYI - putting a backslash in front of many common function names, including trig functions and logarithms, will give you well-formatted formulas instead of treating the letters in the name as if they were variables. For names where this doesn't work, you can enclose them with the text or operatorname instructions: `\text{dim }V` and `\operatorname{dim}W` give $\text{dim }V$ and $\operatorname{dim}W$. Operatorname takes care of spacing automatically, text does not (note the space I put after "dim" in that example).